# Are type family instance proofs possible?

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

First, I started with some typical type-level natural number stuff.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family Plus (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance Plus Z m = m
type instance Plus (S n) m = S (Plus n m)
```

So I wanted to create a data type representing an n-dimensional grid. (A generalization of what is found at [Evaluating cellular automata is comonadic](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html).)

```
data U (n :: Nat) x where
  Point     :: x                           -> U Z     x
  Dimension :: [U n x] -> U n x -> [U n x] -> U (S n) x
```

The idea is that the type `U num x` is the type of a `num`-dimensional grid of `x`s, which is "focused" on a particular point in the grid.

So I wanted to make this a comonad, and I noticed that there's this potentially useful function I can make:

```
ufold :: (x -> U m r) -> U n x -> U (Plus n m) r
ufold f (Point x) = f x
ufold f (Dimension ls mid rs) =
  Dimension (map (ufold f) ls) (ufold f mid) (map (ufold f) rs)
```

We can now implement a "dimension join" that turns an n-dimensional grid of m-dimensional grids into an (n+m)-dimensional grid, in terms of this combinator. This will come in handy when dealing with the result of `cojoin` which will produce grids of grids.

```
dimJoin :: U n (U m x) -> U (Plus n m) x
dimJoin = ufold id
```

So far so good. I also noticed that the `Functor` instance can be written in terms of `ufold`.

```
instance Functor (U n) where
  fmap f = ufold (\x -> Point (f x))
```

However, this results in a type error.

```
Couldn't match type `n' with `Plus n 'Z'
```

But if we whip up some copy pasta, then the type error goes away.

```
instance Functor (U n) where
  fmap f (Point x) = Point (f x)
  fmap f (Dimension ls mid rs) =
    Dimension (map (fmap f) ls) (fmap f mid) (map (fmap f) rs)
```

Well I hate the taste of copy pasta, so my question is this. **How can I tell the type system that `Plus n Z` is equal to `n`**? And the catch is this: you can't make a change to the type family instances that would cause `dimJoin` to produce a similar type error.

Comment: Does putting `Plus n Z ~ n` in the context of the `Functor` instance help?  You just need to replicate that constraint until `n` becomes monomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a nice propositional equality type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family Plus (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance Plus Z m = m
type instance Plus (S n) m = S (Plus n m)

data (:=) :: k -> k -> * where
  Refl :: a := a

data Natural (n :: Nat) where
  Zero :: Natural Z
  Suc  :: Natural n -> Natural (S n)

plusZero :: Natural n -> n := (n `Plus` Z)
plusZero Zero = Refl
plusZero (Suc n) | Refl <- plusZero n = Refl
```

This allows you to prove arbitrary things about your types and bring that knowledge into scope locally by pattern matching on the `Refl`.

One annoying thing is that my `plusZero` proof requires induction over the natural in question, which you won't be able to do by default (since it doesn't exist at runtime). A typeclass for generating `Natural` witnesses would be easy, though.

Another option for your particular case might be just to invert the arguments to plus in your type definition so that you get the `Z` on the left and it reduces automagically. It's often a good first step to make sure your types are as simple as you can make them, but then you'll often need propositional equality for more complicated things, regardless.

Comment: Incidentally, in GHC 7.6 varsyms are type _constructors_ now. So you’d be able to call the equality `(==)` if you want.

Comment: I tried to instantiate an equivalence relation with `Refl Z Z` but the following error occurred. How do I create a value that provides the Reflexive property?

<br> Couldn't match expected type ‘Nat -> Nat -> t’ with actual type ‘EqProp a0 a0’
<br> Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:71:1)
<br> The function ‘Refl’ is applied to two arguments,
<br> but its type ‘EqProp a0 a0’ has none
<br> In the expression: Refl Z Z
<br> In an equation for ‘it’: it = Refl Z Z